# Fill a std::vector with cv:Mat's

Tags: opencv, vector, fill, mat

I've created a struct:

```
struct clusters_t { 
cv::Mat ids; 
cv::Mat means; 
vector<cv::mat> covs; 
cv::Mat weights; 
} clusters;
```

And I have a problem filling the "covs". I reserve memory like I show below but... how can I copy a Mat inside the vector of mats??

```
clusters.covs.clear(); 
clusters.covs.reserve(0);

cv::Mat matrix;

newCovs.copyTo(clusters.covs.at(0)); //<-- DOESN'T WORK... HOW CAN I COPY matrix inside the vector?
```

Comment: Have you studied c++ classes and std::vector? Try `covs.push_back(newCovs)`.

Comment: reserve(0) means to prepare the memory for 0 elements. Try .resize(1) and your example will work if newCovs holds a legal matrix.

Comment: another, maybe better approach is to use `covs.push_back(newCovs.clone())`. Since you wont have any "uninitialized" elements this way. If you are afraid of vector resizes, you can use `.reserve(n)` before with `n` the expected number of elements you will add later (with push_back).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) instead of [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) (and be sure to create at least *one* element).

<strike>Alternatively,</strike>

```
newCovs.copyTo(std::back_inserter(clusters.covs));
```

will work too.

Nope, because it can't work on iterators.

Comment: one thing to take care of when using resize on a `vector<cv::Mat>`: dont use `resize` in this way: `cv::Mat input = someLegalMat; vector.resize(n, input);` because this way, all `n` vector elements will use the same openCV Mat data array.